# How to count serialized shopping cart qty with duplicates records from database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've a `DB` table where I stored shopping cart data with `serialize`. I want to `count` shopping cart `qty` with duplicates row. How can I solve it ?

Suppose, I've two rows and I want to count `qty` for id `2` from those rows.

```
a:3:{s:32:"3c59dc048e8850243be8079a5c74d079";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"3c59dc048e8850243be8079a5c74d079";s:2:"id";s:2:"21";s:3:"qty";s:1:"6";s:5:"price";s:3:"250";s:4:"name";s:20:"Beef SIndhi Biriyane";s:8:"subtotal";i:1500;}s:32:"6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b";s:2:"id";s:2:"29";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:2:"90";s:4:"name";s:14:"Egg Fried Rice";s:8:"subtotal";i:90;}s:32:"98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84";s:2:"id";s:2:"20";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:3:"120";s:4:"name";s:19:"Hyderabadi Biriyane";s:8:"subtotal";i:120;}}
```

and

```
a:3:{s:32:"3c59dc048e8850243be8079a5c74d079";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"3c59dc048e8850243be8079a5c74d079";s:2:"id";s:2:"21";s:3:"qty";s:1:"6";s:5:"price";s:3:"250";s:4:"name";s:20:"Beef SIndhi Biriyane";s:8:"subtotal";i:1500;}s:32:"6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b";s:2:"id";s:2:"29";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:2:"90";s:4:"name";s:14:"Egg Fried Rice";s:8:"subtotal";i:90;}s:32:"98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84";s:2:"id";s:2:"20";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:3:"120";s:4:"name";s:19:"Hyderabadi Biriyane";s:8:"subtotal";i:120;}}
```

Comment: I was try it but did not work for me.

Comment: Can you give better solution for me ?

Comment: I'm not going to write code for you from scratch, especially when I see zero evidence of effort on your part. You need to `unserialize` these strings, which will give you an array you can loop through and do your comparisons, counting, etc.

Comment: whats the exact code you tried? what was the problem you encountered with it?

Comment: I solved my problem. Here is my solving code.
  `$this->db->select( "*, count(substring_index(substring_index(order_data,';',7),':',-1)) AS total", FALSE );
  $this->db->from( "order" );
  $this->db->group_by( "order_data" );
  $res = $this->db->get();
  return ( $res->num_rows() > 0 ) ? $res->result() : false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for this problem.

```
$this->db->select( "*, count(substring_index(substring_index(order_data,';',7),':',-1)) AS total", FALSE );         
$this->db->from( "order" );
$this->db->group_by( "order_data" );

$res = $this->db->get();

return ( $res->num_rows() > 0 ) ? $res->result() : false;
```